# Cannot use import statement outside a module in Jest Test module

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new in Jest. I tried to write test for  basic function which is

```
export const queryValidate = (query) => {
const str = query.replace(/\s+/g, "");
const conditionsArray = [
    str === "",
    str === "{",
    str === "}",
    str === "{}",
];
if (conditionsArray.includes(true)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

};

In my Jest test file like that

```
import { queryValidate } from "./components/QueryValidate";
console.log(queryValidate("{"));
```

I am getting this error message :

> import { queryValidate } from "./components/QueryValidate";

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I cannot understand it is about Jest error or React module error. I try a write dummy test like :`test("Fake test", () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});`
Its work . 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Jest isn't configured correctly. It should process ES modules and it doesn't do that. The question doesn't contain any information on Jest config.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your post. I have a just  devDependencies in package.json ` "devDependencies": {
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5"
    }`

Comment: Jest needs to be configured in order to work like it should. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration . It's provided with pre-made config if you use a template like create-react-app, otherwise you're responsible for configuring it properly. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce your problem, this is required by SO rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, therefore I'm adding an answer. I faced the same issues a while back. 
As Estus has mentioned in the comment, you need to change the Jest config.
You can also have a look at [babel-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest) and then set a babel config file/ .babelrc, along with the preset env.